# what is best way to expose C++Builder code to Delphi

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I am primarily a C++Builder these days and have built (for my own use) a powerful and useful set of classes which wrap around a 3rd party database application. I have a client who uses Delphi. I would like to create a package/active X object/DLL/something exposing some components or classes he could use in Delphi to leverage my code. I'm using XE2 and he is up to date (XE5?). I can update if its helpful. The database in question stores numeric data in time series - so I'm moving around large arrays mostly.

Whats the best strategy for that? I can, of course, build a DLL with C style exported functions, but I'm wondering if there are any cool Embarcadero-ey tools I can use to make it more elegant. I know that components written in C++Builder can't be used in Delphi, but what about packages? The documentation is vague.

I'm having trouble finding information about this topic because all searches on Delphi/C++Builder inter-operability assume the other direction.

Comment: AFAICT, it's not possible to use Builder classes (whether components or not) in Delphi. The Builder object model is totally different than the one used in Delphi, and there was never a Delphi wrapper for it. (I'm not sure there could be, as C++ supports features like multiple inheritance that Delphi doesn't.) The problem you're having finding info is probably because it can't be done. ActiveX would be the only viable alternative I could think of, other than a DLL which provides a flat wrapper. Rudy Velthuis (should be able to find via Google) wrote a couple of articles about this on his site.

Comment: Found it:  http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. It would seem that Interfaces are the way to go.

Comment: @KenWhite, shouldn't that (in slightly longer form) be an answer?

Comment: Johan: I thought about that, but I'm not a huge Builder person, and figured @RemyLebeau would be along and find this, and could probably post a better (technical) answer. If no one does answer, I'll convert mine into one. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: or perhaps Rudy himself, as he is on SO as well

Comment: @MarjanVenema: True. Remy seems to spend a lot more time here, and is primarily a C++ person who also happens to be very knowledgeable about Delphi. I figured he'd see it first (although neither of them appears to have noticed).

Comment: If you want binary interop for components then COM is the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, it's not possible to use Builder classes directly (whether components or not) in Delphi.

The Builder object model is somewhat different from the one used in Delphi, and there was never a Delphi wrapper for it. (I'm not sure there could be, as C++ supports features like multiple inheritance that Delphi doesn't.)

The problem you're having finding info is probably because it can't be done. ActiveX would be the only viable alternative I could think of, other than a DLL which provides a flat wrapper. [Rudy Velthuis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95954/rudy-velthuis) (a member of TeamB who also participates here at SO) wrote an article about this, where he demonstrates both techniques - the flat wrapper and a COM interface - as well as a good explanation of how to apply the techniques. You can find his post [here](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html).